# Segmentation Fault on simple Hello World example?

Tags: c

I'm just starting out with C and I've got this code block for beginners:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf('     /\n');
    printf('    /\n');
    printf('   /\n');
    printf('  /\n');
    printf(' /\n');
    printf('/\n');
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Code Blocks to build and run it. It prints out `Segmentation Fault, core dumped`. The editor is using default gcc compiler.

What's wrong with the code ?

Comment: It should be using double quotes `"` not single quote `'` around strings.

Comment: Try using double quotes i.e. "  Also turn on the warnings

Comment: 'c' is a character. printf takes a string. you should write printf( "\n") etc

Comment: @EdHeal  Thanks for the tip. The editor is set on "Debug" and I can see "build log" tab with warnings so that's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use single quotes calling `printf` instead of double quotes. It's going to turn the first few characters into an integer, and cast that integer as a pointer and access wherever it points as a format string, which is most likely not yet mapped, so segmentation fault.

Use double quotes.

As Ed Heal mentioned, always compile with warnings enabled. C isn't like other languages. Warnings are usually very serious problems.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. That's different from Python. Python doesn't care if I use single or double quotes.

Comment: @wood Certainly, and for people who switch between Python and C it can be a source of grief, especially if they don't have sufficiently many warnings enabled in C. There's another confounding factor: the oddity of multi-character "character" literals. Basically, in most C implementations you can write out an `int` as a "character" literal. C example: `#include <assert.h> int main() { assert('aaaa' == 0x61616161); }`

Comment: @UnslanderMonica: Careful with multi-charcter literals as integers. They're endian dependent and I think int-size dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes for strings:

```
int main() {
    printf("     /\n");
    printf("    /\n");
    printf("   /\n");
    printf("  /\n");
    printf(" /\n");
    printf("/\n");
    return 0;
}
```